# Disable Drag and Drop programatically - fine-uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

Once a user has uploaded a file via any means (file selection, DnD or Cut and Paste), I would like to disable the Upload widget, to prevent users to upload again.

This disabling should be done for a specific upload widget since I may have many on the same page.

Is there a method I can call to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply present an alert/message to the user in your UI once they are no longer able to upload additional files (which you should do no matter what) and then return false in your `onValidateBatch` handler for all subsequently dropped/selected files.  This will prevent files submitted via the file chooser, file submitted via DnD, AND pasted images from being uploaded.